# Ampscript - Change copy text based on Data Extension value True/False

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Hoping if anyone can help with this please. My DE structure is like below:

| Account_ID | Account_mem | segment_1 | segment_2 | segment_3 | segment_4 | segment_5 | segment_6 | segment_7 | segment_8 | segment_9 | segment_10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1234 | False | False | False | False | True | False | False | False | False | False |
| 1234 | 1234 | True | False | False | False | False | True | False | False | False | False |

I want to show different text based on if you are True in which segment. You can't be True in two segments.

So If segment_1 = True show this text
If segment_2 = True show this text
Else show this text

Comment: I assume you are showing a secondary data extension, and not the sendable one? I also assume, there is an account_id field in your sendable DE, allowing you to perform a lookup?

Comment: Asking in a more direct way: What is the subscriberKey in this dataextension? It cannot be Account_Id and it also cannot be Account_mem, since both are not unique. Please attach more details like @LukasLunow has mentioned.